# Existence of Ground State of Dirac equation

Tags: hilbert-space, field-theory, dirac-equation, antimatter, ground-state

In chapter four of [Ryder](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511813900), the author showed that there exists a ground state $|0\rangle$ for the Kelin-Gordon equation, just like the case of the linear harmonic oscillator. However, I was not able to extend this to show the existence of a ground state for the Dirac field equation.

So, how does one prove the existence of a ground state for the Dirac field equation?

Comment: You pointed out a weak point of Dirac theory: energy is not positive definite. Interestingly, charge is.

Answer (score 1):

The Dirac equation spectrum is not bounded from below, hence there is no ground state. To augment this deficiency Dirac postulated that the spectrum of negative energy states was already filled (the so called Dirac Sea). He then predicted the antimatter state (positron) as a hole In this sea.

Comment: Then how do we talk about the ground state when we talk about Dirac field in QFT?

Comment: We have to introduce 2nd quantization or interpret the Dirac equation ground state to be a many_body state. The unaugmented Dirac equation cannot be used as a theory of single particle states.

Comment: If we do that, can we talk about a ground state? Or eqiuvalently (I think it is equivalent, at least), the vacuum?

Comment: In Dirac hole theory the vacuum is the filled sea of negative energy states. It gives the lowest order relativistic corrections to the Hydrgen atom ground state (spin_orbit, etc), but fails to predict the Lamb shift.

Comment: Actually, Dirac predicted that the hole in the Dirac sea was a proton.  This was quickly shown to be incorrect by Weyl, who showed that the electron and hole states had to have the same mass.

Comment: @Buzz  You are correct, that was Dirac"s first reaction but after the proof that the two masses were identical he went further and predicted the existence of the positron which was experimentally confirmed a little over a year latet.